# Error Downloading xls file form CI PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

My model(action.php)

```
class action extends CI_Model{

public function __construct(){
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_data(){
  $query =$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data');
  return $query->result();
}

}
```

My.Controller(Index_cont.php)

```
public function report()
{
  $data = array(
    "user"=> $this->action->get_data());
             //var_dump($data); die();

  $filename ="comment.xls";
  $contents = $this->load->view("Komentar", $data);
  header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
  echo $contents;
}
```

My View(index.php)

```
<form class="" action="<?php echo base_url('index_cont/report'); ?>" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"  type="submit"> Download Report</button>
</form>
```

The problem is my code just view `Komentar.php` (`$contents = $this->load->view("Komentar", $data);`)  and not execute download xls code. If I remove that line, it can download blank xls file. I want to download my data in `Komentar.php` not just blank page.

> ```
> Response Header
> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/tekinf-ci/index_cont/report
> Request Method: POST
> Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
> Remote Address: [::1]:8000
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
> Connection: close
> Content-Length: 1924
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2018 13:59:44 GMT
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> Pragma: no-cache
> Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9
> Set-Cookie: ci_session=ap0r8obbc47nqqcbt1ehrg0u5bffeg17; expires=Tue, 10-Apr-2018 15:59:45 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
> X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.9
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the data loaded by the view so you can't `echo` it, you need to set the 3rd argument to `TRUE`

```
$contents = $this->load->view("Komentar", $data, TRUE); // Assign it to $contents
```

Also use the [Output](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html) library provided by CodeIgniter.

Your code should look like this:

```
public function report()
{
    $data = array("user"=> $this->action->get_data());
    $filename = "comment.xls";
    // Set headers
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/ms-excel')
                 ->set_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary')
                 ->set_header('Cache-Control: private, no-transform, no-store, must-revalidate')
                 ->set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"')
                 ->set_output($this->load->view("Komentar", $data, TRUE));
}
```

Comment: It suppose to be true, but it only view Komentar page in my project. if I remove $this->load->view("Komentar", $data); it can download blank excel page. It's very weird, I don't know maybe I have problem with my config

Comment: same error, do this error related to some config or autoload?

Comment: It's still showing the page as HTML? can you post a screenshot of the response headers after you used my code?

Comment: That's a 500 internal server error, I just tried it and it works fine. You probably have an error with your code, does the controller have any other code other than the one posted? are errors enabled?

Comment: [Full Controller Code](https://pastebin.com/iNYSAUQ7), yes errors enabled but that page don't show error

Comment: It's hard to determine the error, it might be in one of your models, or a miss-configured server, enable logs in CI, refresh the page and see if there are any logs created

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using to create excel file is not the right way. 
Use `PHPExcel` or `PhpSpreadsheet` library to make excel file without errors in opening the file.

**PHPExcel**

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

**PhpSpreadsheet**

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

*PHPExcel Tutorial*

https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/
http://www.webslesson.info/2017/04/generate-excel-file-in-codeigniter-using-phpexcel.html

*PhpSpreadsheet Tutorial*

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/